# Mapping FAQ with Rasa for large dataset (2000+)

Tags: nlp, artificial-intelligence, chatbot, rasa-nlu, rasa-core

RASA is consist of Rasa NLU + Core, I have tested around I understand some part about it. I try to put it into sample practice, and its working perfect.

I plan to bring it into the next level, I wish to create a FAQ system based on RASA stack with help of "tensorflow" backend.

I got over 1200+ pair of Questions and Answers. 1st, NLU would take role to understand and classify the intent along with entity extraction.

2nd it will pass the JSON response to Rasa core where Answers will map or response back to the users. It sounds simple, but as I go and check the Rasa it give something different. Normally, RASA core will response to the User back based on pre-define story along with ==> "utter_". Pre-defined story is good, but for small amount of dataset only. we have to write it manually.

How to deal when dataset or Knowledge based is growing larger such as 1000+ or 5000+, We cannot manually mapping it. I try to look around but cannot find any proper way to deal with it yet.

Previously, I used [Retrieval Model] sklearn TfidfVectorizer as bags of words along with cosine-similarity to compare and return the most similar question index, when index is found Answer will select based on index, but this kind of solution is not effective since the meaning will lost and much more problem.

Anyone got a good solution for this?

Answer (score 6):

First, I want to clarify to the actual architecture:

1. The user sends his messages to the chatbot
2. Rasa Core picks up these messages and passes them on to Rasa NLU, which does the intent recognition (understanding the goal of the user) and extracts entities from the input
3. Based on the recognized intent, entities, and history of the conversation, Rasa Core predicts the next action of the bot

In your case (FAQ bot, many questions) you could try the following, which would lead to relatively simple stories:

```
## User asks for price
* ask_location{"place": "a entity which is extracted by NLU}
  - action_utter_place

# User asks for location
* ask_price{"item": "a entity which is extracted by NLU}
  - action_utter_price

[...]
```

Of course, I would add a bit more paths, e.g. if the user is not happy with the anwer, or the user tries to do chitchat with your chatbot, etc.

In the next step, I would provide all the possible questions in your NLU training data and extract different entities, depending what the question is about. E.g.:

```
## intent:ask_location
- Where is the [cinema](place)
- How do I get to the next [supermarket](place)
- What's the closest [doctor](place)

## intent:ask_price
- How much is it
- What does it cost
- How much is a [ticket](item) for the [cinema](place)
```

In summary, I would not do one intent per question, but rather group several questions within an intent and then extract the entity which narrows it down to the concrete question.

You can then either use a CMS to generate the answers or [custom actions](https://rasa.com/docs/core/customactions/#custom-actions). Based on the extracted entities (e.g. *place* and *item*) you can then query your database and generate the answer.

Comment: The answer is using the RASA framework for creating a template based chatbot. It works by interaction, that means a signaling games takes place. What is missing is a grounded grammar. That is is an ontology of topics which are available and how they fit together. For example, a question about the supermarket is a subquestion of a location question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean here by saying  `*but this kind of solution is not effective since the meaning will lost and much more problem.*`. For single turn question/answers the Official Rasa method would be to use retrieval-actions as you suggested. We found this a bit cumbersome, and we implemented a simple classifier on top of Universal Encoder embeddings.

i.e. The bot has an `ask_faq` intent, under which all the ~1000 single turn questions are grouped. All these are mapped to a action `action_answer_faq`. In the action, the secondary classifier we built especially for these ~1000 questions will be used to infer the correct response id. An internal database would contain the response text ( which can change as the business user wants without requiring a change in the model) .